# Alternative for creating Database and inside Database having schemes like Oracle in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.7

In oracle we have database inside database we have schemes and inside schemas we have tables.
 For Example consider the following  scenario 
I have 2 databases like Database1 and Database2.
In Database1 it have Schema-A and Schema-B and users u1 and u2   these 2 schemas have tables.
In Database2 it has same schema-A and schema-B and users u1 and u2 and these schemas have some tables.

In MySQL both database and Schema are same. So How can do the above scenario in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can get extra levels in the hierarchy by:

- running multiple instances of MySQL servers - you can run multiple MySQL servers on the same host using different ports and sockets
- using prefixes (e.g. `a_`, `b_`) in the names of tables or databases

The database or table name prefixes can be used mostly for visual purposes, although you can also give grants based on prefixes, e.g.:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `db1\_%`.* TO 'user1'@'%';
```

In the above grant, `user1` is allowed to run DML queries on all databases with names starting with `db1_`.